# How to get Visual Studio Intellisense to discover an inherited subclass?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I have a scenario where Visual Studio (2012) Intellisense is failing to recognize a subclass which is defined in an inherited class. It's probably best demonstrated with a simple example:

```
public class Shape {

    public class SubShape {
    }

}

public class Circle : Shape {
}
```

So I have a Shape class with a SubShape subclass, and Circle which inherits from Shape.

If I then try to instantiate an instance of SubShape with `new Circle.SubShape()`, I get no results from Visual Studio's Intellisense after `new Circle.`. Everything builds correctly with no syntax errors.

If I reference the class from the base class with `new Shape.SubShape()`, the Intellisense works. It works as well if I initially leave off the `new` keyword -- so typing `Circle.` presents me with `SubShape` as an option.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, version `11.0.61030.00 Update 4`.

**Update:** I have ReSharper disabled, but if I turn it on and choose to use ReSharper's Intellisense instead of Visual Studio's, everything works as expected.

Comment: Have you tried with 2013? I have 2013 (Professional) and Resharper and it works as you describe here. Not sure whether it is Reharper or VS2013 doing it though

Comment: Thanks! Can you try disabling ReSharper and see if it still works? I think you can do it easily through the Tools -> Options -> ReSharper dialog, on 2012 anyway. If I turn ReSharper on and choose to use ReSharper's Intellisense intead of VS's, it works for me as well... so in 2012 it seems to be a Visual Studio bug that ReSharper fixes.

Comment: Just disabled it and it looks like it is a ReSharper feature :(. I'll test with VS2013 Ultimate when I get home and see whether it exists there

Comment: Just tested, it is the Resharper's feature.

Comment: CodeRush also has this feature :)

Comment: This is no accident.  Whatever poor sap is going to maintain your code some day will lose clumps of head-hair trying to find that class back.  He'll look at Circle.cs and have no hope of finding it there.  There is no point in avoiding the true name of the class, inheriting it doesn't change it in any way.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an Intellisense bug (very minor), also happens in VS2010.

Oddly enough, declaring a variable do has Intellisense, that is both

```
Shape.SubShape s;
Circle.SubShape s;
```

when typed, will list Subshape after dot.